# java Inheritence removing a child object

Tags: java, loops

I finished the assignment that I was working on.
But i'm trying to modify it a little

What I'm trying to do is remove a record and I want ot use an iterator to do it.
if I was using a for each loop it would be something like this.

```
for(People someone : person)
    (someone instanceof Parent)
        ((Parent)someone.whatever
```

How would you do that with an iterator?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your for-each loop will use the iterator and what you've written will work if you simple move it from pseudo code to Java. `for(Object o : iterable)if(o instance of Y)((Y)o).f();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Parent> myList = new ArrayList<Parent>();
    Iterator<Parent> iterator = myList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Parent p = iterator.next();
        if (p instanceof Child) {
          //do something with the Child
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys.An important lesson learnt but never to be forgotten